# Настроить SSH на Headless RPi Ubuntu (Server)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, wlan

Стоит задача установить Ubuntu Server на Raspberry Pi 4 B, запустить в режиме Headless (нет клавиатуры, мыши и монитора, только два LED чтобы понять жива она или нет и два Wi-Fi адаптера, с которыми она может оперировать), дождаться чтобы она подключилась к Wi-Fi сети, подключиться к ней по локальной сети с помощью PuTTY. Казалось бы всё просто, но все гайды предназначены для Raspbian (т. е. Debian), а те, что для Ubuntu запускают SSH через командную строку (которой, как я уже сказал, нет; подключиться к монитору не выйдет даже один раз). Таким образом, мы должны сделать это путём изменения файлов в SD-карте, которую мы только вставим.

Как сделать загрузочную SD-карту с Ubuntu Server для RPi 4, чтобы она автоматически подключалась к сети Wi-Fi и запускала SSH-сервер.

*Доп. проблема: один из Wi-Fi адаптеров малинки хромает, и поэтому подключаться надо не с wlan0, а с wlan1*

Comment: вот так пробовали https://superuser.com/questions/469039/wpa-supplicant-for-dual-wlan ?

Comment: https://andreyex.ru/stati/kak-vklyuchit-ssh-na-raspberry-pi/ и https://linuxhint.com/raspberry_pi_headless_mode_ubuntu/